# Multiplying two 24 bit digits in Verilog

Tags: verilog, multiplication

I am trying to write code that multiplies two 24-bit numbers and results in a 32-bit number. I have tried to do it using such a bit-by-bit method but I think something is wrong.

This is my code:

```
result[0] <= arg1[0] & arg2[0];
        
for (i = 1; i < 24; i = i + 1) begin
    result[i] <= arg1[0] & arg2[i] | arg1[i] & arg2[0] | result[i-1];
end

for (i = 24; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
    result[i] <= 0;
end
```

I tried to do testbench and the result is always 0 so I wonder if multiplying is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog is a high level language.
Multiply numbers using the multiply operator.
Synthesis understands the multiply operator and will infer a multiplier in hardware.
Simulation understands multiplication natively.

As stated in the comments, the size of the result of 24 bits * 24 bits is 48 bits.
In order to obtain a 32 bits number, take from the low end 32 of the 48-bit number.
Taking the low bits produces truncation/wrapping behavior when the 48 bit result is greater than 32 bits.  You could write code to have saturation rather than truncation, if that is needed.

Example:

```
module mul (
  input  wire [23:0] a,
  input  wire [23:0] b,
  output reg  [47:0] c
);
  
  always @(*)
    c = a * b;
  
endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
module tb ();
  
  reg  [23:0] a,b;
  reg  [47:0] c;
  wire [31:0] c_32;
  
  mul mul
  (
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .c(c)
  );
  
  // take 32 bits
  assign c_32 = c[31:0];
  
  initial
    begin
      $monitor("a = %0d, b=%0d, c=%0d, c_32 = %0d",a,b,c,c_32);
      a = 1;
      b = 1;
      #2;
      a = 2;
      b = 2;
      #2;
      a = 64;
      b = 64;
      #2 ;
      a = 24'hffffff;
      b = 24'hffffff;
      #2;
    end
  
endmodule
```

Produces:

```
a = 1, b=1, c=1, c_32 = 1
a = 2, b=2, c=4, c_32 = 4
a = 64, b=64, c=4096, c_32 = 4096
a = 16777215, b=16777215, c=281474943156225, c_32 = 4261412865
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code, it seems that you are trying to perform bitwise multiplication, which is not the correct way to multiply two numbers. Instead, you should perform a bit-by-bit accumulation of partial products, similar to the long multiplication method taught in school.

```
module multiplier_24bit (
    input [23:0] arg1,
    input [23:0] arg2,
    output reg [31:0] result
);

always @(*) begin
    integer i, j;
    result = 32'b0;

    for (i = 0; i < 24; i = i + 1) begin
        for (j = 0; j < 24; j = j + 1) begin
            if (arg1[i] & arg2[j]) begin
                result[i+j] = result[i+j] + 1;
            end
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

This Code defines a module multiplier_24bit with two 24-bit input arguments arg1 and arg2, and a 32-bit output result. The nested loops inside the always block perform the multiplication in the same way as described in the previous C code example. Note that the non-blocking assignment (<=) has been replaced with a blocking assignment (=) since we are inside an always @(*) block, which is a combinational block.

Comment: What happens if `i+j` becomes larger than 31?